How to freeze the hand movement

Hi,
I'm new to blender rigging. I copied a movement from Mixamo to my own rig, now I want to freeze the hand movements (only) and also want it to rest it's hand (as I can not make it grip, no finger bone) on the handle of the object in front of it.
Please help and forgive if you found it a stupid question.

If the action comes from Mixamo the bones probably don"t have IK constraint, the first thing would be to create an IK constraint on the forearm, with a controller bone, and give the controller bone a Child Of constraint with the bar as target so that the forearms and hands stay still

There is an official Mixamo add-on for Blender that adds IK controls to the rigged character so you don't need to create them yourself. It looks like that you need this fix to make it work in Blender 4.x (I haven't tried it).

If the action comes from Mixamo the bones probably don't have IK constraint, the first thing would be to create an IK constraint on the forearm, with a controller bone, and give the controller bone a Child Of constraint with the bar as target so that the forearms and hands stay still.

Thanks for your reply. I will try this and let you know. Though I tried "child of" constrain earlier but without IK bone, it didn't work.
